# Making phone call with formatted number from app

Tags: ios4

I'm looking for a little help with making phone call from my app. The phone number is formatted as (###) ###-####.

In my `.h` I have this:

```
 IBOutlet UITextView    *PhoneNumber;
```

In my `.m` I tried these:

```
- (IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",PhoneNumber.text]]];
```

I'm unable to make it dial out the number. But when I tried this its work.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:#########"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone) site, the dashes should be ok. Just remove the parenthesis.

Comment: I think spaces are a problem, too.